# how to redirect a page from web service and return the value of textbox c#

Tags: c#, web-services, asp.net-mvc-5

```
public void getuserinfo(string username, string password, string role, string errormsg)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);
    List<object> logininfo = new List<object>();
    if(role=="Admin" || role=="Super Admin")
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from [admin] where userid='" + username + "' and password ='" + password + "'", con);
        con.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        if(dt.Rows.Count>0)
        {
            // want to redirect to welcome page if condition satisfied.
        }
        else
        {
           //want to show the label error message(declare as string errormsg)
        }
    }
}
```

This is my webservice it will validate role(user will select from dropdownlist), username(textbox) and password(textbox) if all the validation completed the page should be redirected to welcome page and if information provided by user is not correct, label should be visible on

> login page And i cant return the values of the textbox, this is the error when i return something(return keyword must not be followed by object expression)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Return value from this methord `getuserinfo(string username, string password, string role, string errormsg)`  get it to your action method from action method you can redirect user to another page using

```
 RedirectToAction("Welcomepage", "Account");
```

Comment: i cant return the values of the textbox, this is the error when i return something(return keyword must not be followed by object expression)

Comment: if you want to return something then you have to change the method signature from void to what you want to return

Comment: can you please explain me